# Error attempt to insert nil object from objects

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-asset-library-to-base64 for converting my image to base64 format.

But I am getting the following error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Can anyone tell me how to solve this.

Comment: can you provide us a code snippet? maybe one, where you invoke the library

Comment: var ReadImageData = require('NativeModules').ReadImageData;
componentWillMount(){
   //alert("fdfkdl"+this.props.rowData.card_back)
 img_front="http://myappdemo.com:5005/"+this.props.rowData.card_front
 img_back="http://myappdemo.com:5005/"+this.props.rowData.card_back
 ReadImageData.readImage(uri, (imageBase64) => {
console.log(imageBase64);
});

}

Comment: what is `uri` in your `ReadImageData.readImage(uri, ......`?

Comment: uri is the image I get from the api that I want to convert to base 64